# Add C library to docker

Tags: c, docker, dockerfile

I have a golang project with c library dependencies(e.g pbc).
I create a dockerfile:

```
 FROM golang:1.9.6-alpine3.7

 RUN mkdir -p /go/src/app

 WORKDIR /go/src/app

 COPY . /go/src/app

 RUN apk add --update git gcc build-base gmp flex bison

 RUN go-wrapper download

 RUN go-wrapper install

 CMD ["go-wrapper", "run", "-web"]

 EXPOSE 8000
```

However I dont understand how to provide a pbc-library, as it's standalone library - https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/howto.html

Additional this library linked dynamically.
What should I do?

Comment: Why does the title say “c++” if the question is about a C library?

Answer (score 1):

Add the docker commands to download, compile and install the library on your docker image.

```
RUN wget https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/files/pbc-0.5.14.tar.gz && \
    tar -xvf pbc-0.5.14.tar.gz && \
    cd pbc-0.5.14 && \
    ./configure --prefix=$HOME/.local && \
    make && make install

RUN rm pbc-0.5.14.tar.gz && rm -rf pbc-0.5.14
```

this is of course a very simple way, you need to know how you want to compile it, and what custom flags to use.